What is the method to increment letters in a String in Java?
How would I increment letters in a string in Java, taking into account output needs to be on one line and the space between the words?
String str = "Hello World";

I want the output to be:
Jgnnq Yqtnf

I tried this and it works (new code added at 3.42am GMT):
public class Strings{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="Hello World";
        String line= "";
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        
        for(char i: arr) {
            line += (i+=2);
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

Edit....
The code I wrote would then work for both words...but I want there now to be a space between the two words and for it to be on one line.
Sorry for confusion and re-writing the question...

Yes, you have to loop through the strings in the array one at a time.  You will end up with TWO loops: one for each string in the array, then one for each character in the string.

unless, of course, you split your String on "nothing" so you end up with a string array that consists of individual letters (but that will include space, too)

Don't forget that y maps to a and z maps to b.

Character provides a static .isAlphabetic(codepoint) which you can use to check which characters are alphabets which you can then increment

"Incrementing a letter" is not a well-defined concept.  And your example doesn't clarify this. If you want this Q&A to be other people, you need to specify what >you< mean by it.  (If you don't want to do that, my vote would be to close this Question as "needs clarity".)

For example, what does "z" increment to?  What about "Z"?  What about a hyphen or a space character?  What about an accented letter?  What about a Greek letter?  What restrictions you are placing on "letter"?  What should happen with a non-letter?

@StephenC z increments to b. The other factors, not too worried about at the minute. Have now worked on the code to get all output characters on 1 line. Am still working on how to put a space between the 2 words...

Put your clarifications into the question.  Future readers are not going to wade through a bunch of comments to figure out what you what you were actually asking.  The question needs to be clear independently of the comments.

Also ... updating your question to add new problems (e.g. adding spaces between words) is bad form.  You are changing the question.  Changing the question tends to render existing answers incomplete or incorrect.  And asking multiple things in one question is liable to lead to be closed as "needs more focus".  Remember: the purpose of StackOverflow is to build a library of useful questions and answers ... not to be a forum to help individuals solve their problems.

This is an ancient cipher known as a Caesar shift (or Caesar cipher - because Julius Caesar used it in his letters).

Here's a version using ASCII characters.  You could also use codepoints.
This allows for any value to increment letters and adjusts letters via wrap around exceeding 'Z' or 'z'.
String s = "Hello World!";
System.out.println(incrementLetters(s, 2));

prints
Jgnnq Yqtnf!


If the character is not a letter, use as is.
otherwise increment properly based on case.
'A' + ((c - 'A') + inc) % 26

add the base character, to the letter plus increment and
use the remainder to adjust for wrap around.


Using the conditional operator, apply the above for 'A' and 'a'

public static String incrementLetters(String str, int inc) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int c : str.toCharArray()) {

        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            c = Character.isUpperCase(c) 
                    ? 'A' + ((c - 'A') + inc) % 26 // upper case
                    : 'a' + ((c - 'a') + inc) % 26;// lower case
        }

        sb.append((char) c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


Try this (for the original question that uses an array of String as input):
private final String incrementString( final String s )
{
  final var buffer = s.codePoints().map( cp -> cp + 2 ).toArray();
  final var retValue = new String( buffer, 0, buffer.length );
  return retValue;
}

String[] str = {"Hello","World"};
str = str.stream.map( this::incrementString ).toArray( String[]::new );

As usual, the error handling is missing; in particular a null check in incrementString() would not do harm.
Basically, incrementString() iterates over the characters in a single String (ok, more precisely, over the codepoints that corporates that String) and finally, a new String is build from the resulting array.
The last line is iterating over the Strings in the array and calls incrementString() on them.
Of course you can also increment on chars – as long as you deal with ASCII characters only. But if your code should work on all available Unicode characters, you should go for the codepoints. Bad thing is that there are some invalid codepoints, so that you think about an increment method that continues incrementing until the result is valid again:
private final int incrementCodepoint( final int codepoint )
{
  var newCodepoint = codepoint + 1;
  do
  {
    ++newCodepoint;
  } 
  while( !Character.isDefined( newCodepoint ) || Character.isISOControl( newCodepoint ) || Character.isWhitespace( newCodepoint ) );
  return newCodepoint;
} 

The overflow on int is expected and will not do much harm other than causing the method to run s… äh … very long time. There is room for improvement …
Oh, and if you really want to increment only letters (not digits), you can have the condition in the while like this:
…
while( !Character.isDefined( newCodepoint ) || !Character.isLetter( newCodepoint ) );


For the new requirement that defines a mere String as input, I would use this:
private final int incrementCodepoint( final int codepoint )
{
  var retValue = codepoint + 1;
  do
  {
    ++newCodepoint;
  } 
  while( !Character.isDefined( retValue ) || !Character.isLetter( retValue ) );
  return newCodepoint;
} 

var str = "Hello World";
var buffer = str.codePoints().map( this::incrementCodePoint ).toArray();
str = new String( buffer, 0, buffer.length ) );


There are many ways to reach the same result, I show you one:
  String str = "Hello World"; 
  char[] array = str.toCharArray();
  for( char c: array ) {

       // here we discard the characters that do not correspond to a 
       // letter, which will be printed without being modified.
     if( c > 64 && c < 90 || c > 97 && c < 122 ) {
        System.out.println( c += 2 );
     }
     else {
        System.out.println( c );
     }
  }

this prints: -> Jgnnq Yqtnf
